# GIT - Error received during Clone and Pull requests

Tags: git, rhodecode

I receive the following error after attempting to Clone a project into my workspace:

```
Cloning into '<MyProjectName>'...
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 500
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I am using the RhodeCode front end to manage our code repositories.  I don't have direct access to the server that RhodeCode runs on, but I am working to get a look at the error logs.  I will update with error log information if I can get to it.

I've read a few articles that indicate that this error might be caused by the size of the repository that I am attempting to Clone.  I am able to successfully Clone a project that is 139.2MB in size.  The size of the projects that fails the Clone operation are 199MB in size.

Does anyone think that the size of my project is causing the error I am seeing?

I did have an admin look at the server memory usage while I performed the Clone operation (he monitored the server that RhodeCode runs on) and he told me that the system memory usage wasn't the problem.

Not sure how to proceed at this point.  Thanks for any suggestions!

RhodeCode Version: 2.2.4
Git Version: 1.8.4

Edit with additional information:

I was able to (finally) get on the server that contains the RhodeCode installation.  I'd like to find the error logs and I'm not sure where to look.  This is what I see:

- C:/Program Files/RhodeCode
- C:/Git
- C:/GitStack
- C:/rhodecode-224

  As you can tell, we are running on a Windows Server.  I'm not sure what the difference is between Git and GitStack.  I am assuming that the rhodecode-224 is an installation package.

08/22/2016 Edit: I was able to learn how to look at the RhodeCode server's output and I gathered the following bit of information...

```
2016-08-22 11:26:56.733 ERROR [waitress] Exception when serving /<MyProjectName>/git-upload-pack

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\RhodeCode Enterprise\system\Lib\site-packages\waitress\channel.py", line 332, in service task.service()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\RhodeCode Enterprise\system\Lib\site-packages\waitress\task.py", line 173, in service self.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\RhodeCode Enterprise\system\Lib\site-packages\waitress\task.py", line 388, in execute app_iter = self.channel.server.application(env, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\RhodeCode Enterprise\system\Lib\site-packages\paste\gzipper.py", line 40, in __call__ response.finish_response(app_iter)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\RhodeCode Enterprise\system\Lib\site-packages\paste\gzipper.py", line 85, in finish_response output.write(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\gzip.py", line 236, in write self.fileobj.write( self.compress.compress(data) )

  MemoryError: out of memory
```

So, now, at least I know that I am dealing with some type of space limitation.

I have checked the server that our RhodeCode installation runs on during the Clone operation that fails.  The server has 8Gig of memory.  During the Clone operation I always see 3Gig of space as being available.

We tried the following modification in the 'production.ini' file:

```
## WAITRESS ##
use = egg:waitress#main
## number of worker threads
threads = 5
## MAX BODY SIZE 100GB = 107374182400  200GB = 214748364800
max_request_body_size =  214748364800 
## use poll instead of select, fixes fd limits, may not work on old
## windows systems.
#asyncore_use_poll = True
## COMMON ##
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 5000
```

We doubled the MaxRequestBodySize hoping this would make a difference and it didn't.

Are there other size restrictions in place that are specific to the RhodeCode server?  Anything else I can look at or modify during the Clone operation?

We are looking into what it will take to upgrade to version 3.8, but I wanted to mention what we found and tried.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with RhodeCode, but I think the bug is in your in-between layer. Git has been around for years and the Linux kernel is, which is a very large code-base, is under Git control w/o issues. I don't see your clone URL, but HTTP-500 errors indicate the server-side layer between you and your repository had a problem (e.g. script crashed). Also, make sure you're using the *latest* version of Git (1.8 is way too old).

Comment: This error happens if communication breaks or timeout occurs. Maybe RhodeCode lost connection to the remote Git? I can see this when I push large repo (over 500M) to the remote. Funny thing is that although I see this message, nothing seems to be messed up. Can you check up if the clone actually succeded?

Comment: sandalone - The Clone operation times out (I would say 5 to 6 minutes and then I receive the error).  The project isn't transferred into my local workspace (the Clone did not succeed).  I can Clone smaller projects, but not the one I need.

Comment: ray - My clone command (and URL) looks like this: git clone http://<myUserName>@<NameOfServer>:5000<ProjectName>

Comment: sounds like another case of a GIT UI making GIT far more confusing than it actually is if you learn the command line options.

Answer (score 0):

Dmitry from RhodeCode is here! Upgrading to RhodeCode 4.3 (the latest version at the moment) might solve the issue since we introduced many performance improvements over the last two years.

[RhodeCode CE](https://rhodecode.com/) is free and open source. The drawback is that 4.3 doesn't support Windows out of the box, so you may need to do a fresh-install and configure it to run as a Virtual Machine.

[RhodeCode EE](https://rhodecode.com/register) is licensed per user, however it has an already pre-configured VM image to run on Windows. You'll get quite a performance boost too.